# Unzipping file in phonegap using zip.js

Tags: cordova, unzip, cordova-3

am using PhoneGap Cordova 3.3.0 and latest version of [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/core-api.html). The script is able to get the list of files inside the archive but is unable to get any binary data. Am using the fix by [Hugeen](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js/pull/70) but no luck.

```js
function decompress(fullsavepath, filename){
    zip.useWebWorkers = false;
    file_system.root.getFile("app_cache/temp.zip", {}, function(fileEntry){
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {

            zip.createReader(new zip.BlobReader(file), function(reader) {

                // get all entries from the zip
                reader.getEntries(function(entries) {
                    if (entries.length) {
                        //Output zip file contents
                        for(var i=0; i<entries.length;i++){
                            console.log(entries[i].filename);
                        }

                        //Try to decompress file no. 3
                        console.log('---- entries[2] '+entries[2].filename);
                        entries[2].getData(new zip.BlobWriter(), function(unzipData){
                            console.log(unzipData);
                        },null, null);
                    }
                });
            }, null);

        })

    },null);
}
```

Here is my console log with the relevant messages:

```
Console: ----entries[2] photoalbum/bpage1.jpg at file:///android_asset/www/dl/index.html:315
Console: processMessage failed: Message: S01 File821048650 AUEsDBBQAAAAIAEFVCEMFqmCrQAsHAMa3BwASAAAA at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1034
Console: processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1035
Console: processMessage failed: Stack: TypeError: undefined is not a function
Console:     at inflate (file:///android_asset/www/dl/js/vendor/zip/zip.js:429:18)
Console:     at file:///android_asset/www/dl/js/vendor/zip/zip.js:600:16
Console:     at BlobWriter.init (file:///android_asset/www/dl/js/vendor/zip/zip.js:297:4)
Console:     at file:///android_asset/www/dl/js/vendor/zip/zip.js:596:12
Console:     at [object Object].<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/dl/js/vendor/zip/zip.js:203:5)
Console:     at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.core.file/www/FileReader.js:352:20
Console:     at Object.callbackFromNative (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:292:54)
Console:     at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1029:21)
Console:     at Function.processMessages (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1063:13)
Console:     at pollOnce (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:933:17) at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1036
```

------ **UPDATE 2014-04-07** -------------

In the end we used an alternative approach to solve the problem. Google developed a native plugin for Android and iOS - https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/zip

It is quite straight forward, and honestly one of the rare plugins we used that succeeded doing what we needed on first try.

Example:

```
 zip.unzip("cdvfile://localstorage/downloaded.zip", 
           "cdvfile://localstorage/my_data/path/", 
           function(){
              console.log('Zip decompressed successfully');
           }
 );
```

PS: Cordova has since been updated to 3.4.0 - My original question used paths like `file:///android_asset/www` which has all been replaced with the new `cdvfile://`

Comment: stupid question, but just in case : did you add the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ?

Comment: Hi @QuickFix, yes I have. The file am trying to unzip was first downloaded from HTTP, then this script would take over and unzip it.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this ?

Comment: if you solved please add as answer and mark it with selected answer. Thank you

Comment: Done as per your suggestion @nerkn, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-- COPIED FROM MY EDIT ABOVE--

In the end we used an alternative approach to solve the problem. Google developed a native plugin for Android and iOS - https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/zip

It is quite straight forward, and honestly one of the rare plugins we used that succeeded doing what we needed on first try.

Example:

```
 zip.unzip("cdvfile://localstorage/downloaded.zip", 
           "cdvfile://localstorage/my_data/path/", 
           function(){
              console.log('Zip decompressed successfully');
           }
 );
```

PS: Cordova has since been updated to 3.4.0 - My original question used paths like `file:///android_asset/www` which has all been replaced with the new `cdvfile://`

Comment: What is your experience with performance? Unzipping larger files take a long time. 130MB took about 10 min. on my S5.

Comment: We were using Galaxy Tab 2 and a Nexus 5. We had similar file sizes, around ~90-120MB containing a video around ~80MB and some smaller JPG and HTML. Takes about 3-4 mins to unzip. Read/ write performed from the SD Card for the Tab 2.

Comment: Well, I presume my performance issue is due to the number of files - about 50.000 very small JPG (map tiles).

Comment: This always returns `-1`

Comment: @AbdulSadikYalcin The solution was posted back 2014. I doubt it's still applicable. But `-1` usually indicates there's a problem extracting, could be the destination is not available or the archive is corrupted. To be safe, check latest docs and download the latest package.

Comment: @JamesWong not needed anymore. I ended up writing my own plugin. Works perfectly.

Comment: @AbdulSadikYalcin Hi Abdul, could you please share your solution ?

Comment: @subin272 Sure - join me here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186844/cordova-unzip