# Using Javascript how can files be unzipped on mobile device from an app that is built using PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, zip, unzip

Using Phonegap 3.2.0, I am downloading a zip file and placing it in my mobile device. I am not supposed to use any Phonegap plugin to unzip this file.

So, using JavaScript how can files be unzipped or deflated or extracted from a *.zip file on mobile device from a mobile app that is built using PhoneGap?

**PS:** I am looking for a **JavaScript based solution** not a Phonegap plugin or Phonegap related solution. My zip file contains multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

Visit this : [Unzipping file in phonegap using zip.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334174/unzipping-file-in-phonegap-using-zip-js)

Zip.js here : http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/core-api.html

Comment: Thanks @nitin, I had already gone through these 2 links. The first link talks about zip.js as the solution but failed in mobile hence the person who posted the question had to use MobileChromeApps/zip which is a Phonegap plugin. Since, it is phonegap plugin, I cant use it. Second link is the link to zip.js, it works on desktops but fails terribly on mobile devices. I've checked that personally. Also, zip.js does not extract the files to your mobile device. 
Hence, both the solutions dont work for me.